# How can I convert integer to date with ddmmyy in iSeries DB2 in cognos framework manager query

Tags: date, casting, cognos

i have no luck on research and got the solution on this...
attempting to convert/cast given integer (eg: 301193) to date with format 1993-11-30. I need the date data type to build my cube..
and i should use 'Database only' or 'limited local' for query processing mode...

Please advice. Thank you very much...

Comment: It seems quite unconventional and problematic to store a date as an integer like that. What would happen with an invalid input such as the integer `0` or `311193`. Are all dates in the 20th century? When is `301100`?

Comment: Yea.. this is the problem.. but this is what I am getting from Host.. is the design from source.. apart from using _maketimestamp and substring.. i am looking for the db function which allows to direct conversion..